# Recursively Defined Functions for string

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, computer-science

Let be a recursively defined language over the alphabet Σ = {0,1} as follows. Basis case: ε ∈ L, where ε denotes the empty string. Recursive step: if s ∈ L
[Recursively Defined Functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR0PV.png)

can any one help me please ?
it's really complicated for me

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: @Nelu It's rather better for you to explain your questions in clear and concise words, which shows you actually understand the question and care to learn about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)
$$
\epsilon 
\\
00
\\
0110
\\
010010
\\
01000010
$$
Note in each step we replace $ \epsilon $ by some rule such as $ 0s0 \ or \ 0 \epsilon 0 $

Comment: I really appreciate your help, THANK YOU !

Comment: Hey you can ask anything here :)

Comment: what about c, do you have any idea about it ? or how can I solve it ?